# JQuery AJAX POST Message Issue

Tags: jquery

I'm doing an AJAX POST call and it works fine except for one thing. After I do a submit, I get the success/failure message but when I click on submit again, it shows another success/failure message without clearing the first one. It keeps adding a new one. How can I make it to show just one for each submit?

```
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>'

        $(".ap-webmethod").click(function () {

            if ($('#aspnetForm').valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: pageUrl + '/ProcessADRequest',
                    data: '{USER: "' + $("[id$='_userName']").text() + '", SSNID: "' + $("[id$='_empLast4Txt']").val() + '", DOB: "' + $("[id$='_empDobTxt']").val() + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) { $('.post-msg').append("<label>" + response.d + "</label>"); },
                    failure: function (response) { $('.post-msg').append("<label>" + response.d + "</label>"); }

                });


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `append(...)` where as you need to use `val(...)`

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of Append, I had to use html. Val did not work.

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry, I misread what you were trying to insert into `.post-msg`. `.val()` works for setting the value of elements like `input`s where as you were wanting to insert some `html`. My mistake - serves me right for writing answers just before I went to bed!

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the old message first using `$('.post-msg').remove()`.  I'd do something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pageUrl + '/ProcessADRequest',
                data: '{USER: "' + $("[id$='_userName']").text() + '", SSNID: "' + $("[id$='_empLast4Txt']").val() + '", DOB: "' + $("[id$='_empDobTxt']").val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) 
                { 
                    $('.post-msg').remove('.msg'); 
                    $('.post-msg').append("<label class='msg'>" + response.d + "</label>");         
                },
                failure: function (response) 
                { 
                    $('.post-msg').remove('.msg'); 
                    $('.post-msg').append("<label class='msg'>" + response.d + "</label>"); 
                }

            });
```